# How do I use functions within a class injected as a task without using calling .Result?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dependency-injection, blazor

I am attempting to implement the answer given by lolsharp here: [gRPC-Web Channel Authentication with Blazor Webassembly via Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146743/grpc-web-channel-authentication-with-blazor-webassembly-via-dependency-injection)

They inject a Task of type GrpcChannel, where GrpcChannel is a class:

```
@inject Task<GrpcChannel> Channel
```

This is done since the channel is registered using async.

I tried using a function within this class like so:

`GetAllResponse getAllResponse = await Channel.Result.GetAllAsync(new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Empty());`

But this fails with the error "Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime", since the mechanism cannot be supported on single-threaded webassembly (as explained at [Blazor Startup Error: System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211539/blazor-startup-error-system-threading-synchronizationlockexception-cannot-wait)).

How can I use functions within the Channel class within a Razor page if channel is registered asynchronously?

Edit: as requested, here is the dependency as declared in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton(async services =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In addsingleton");
            var config = services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
            #if DEBUG
            var baseUri = "http://localhost:8999/";
#else
            var baseUri = "[mysite]";
#endif
            Console.WriteLine("About to set new httpclient");
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(new 
GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));
            
            var scopedFactory = 
services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            using (var scope = scopedFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                
                var authenticationService = 
scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>();

                var tokenResult = await 
authenticationService.RequestAccessToken();
                
                if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
                {
                    var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.Value))
                        {
                            metadata.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer 
{token.Value}");
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    });

                    var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri, new 
GrpcChannelOptions { HttpClient = httpClient, Credentials = 
ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials) });
                    var client = new 
GrpcServices.GrpcServicesClient(channel);
                    return client;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gRPC-Web Channel Authentication with Blazor Webassembly via Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146743/grpc-web-channel-authentication-with-blazor-webassembly-via-dependency-injection)

Comment: can you post your dependency in the startup.cs that you are using?

Comment: @Hostel No, that is where the question I have comes from.  The second answer there stops right before explaining how to use the class.

Comment: @Dan I have added the dependency from Program.cs.

Comment: Prevent doing anything that involves I/O during object resolution. This makes resolution fragile and untestable. Instead, you should be able to [compose your object graphs with con confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/).

Comment: @Steven thank you but I don't understand how I can resolve the object before performing the I/O in this case.  That is essentially what I am asking.  Is the "object" you are referring to here the class?  How do I "resolve" it in this case, given that it is declared as the type argument of a Task?

Comment: Instead of injecting a `Task<Channel>` create an abstraction that gives access to it (e.g. `interface IChannelProvider { Task<Channel> GetChannel(); }`) and inject that into the view. This allows you to postpone IO until after resolution.

Comment: You are caching the `GrpcChannel` indefinitely. This means that it will be reused for all users of the application? Is that correct, considering that you are creating the channel using a specific security token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent having to call `.Result` on `Channel`, you will have to await it. For instance:

```cs
var channel = await Channel;
GetAllResponse getAllResponse =
    await channel.GetAllAsync(new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Empty());
```

Side note: As I mentioned in the comments, you should typically want to prevent doing anything that involves I/O during object resolution, becuase it makes object resolution fragile and untestable. Instead, you should be able to compose your object graphs with con confidence, as expressed [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/) by Mark Seemann. You can do this by postponing the creation of the Task by hiding it behind an abstraction. For instance:

```cs
public interface IGrpcChannelProvider
{
    Task<GrpcChannel> Channel { get; }
}
```

This allows you to move all the registration code into an implementation for `IGrpcChannelProvider`:

```cs
public sealed class GrpcChannelProvider : IGrpcChannelProvider, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IConfiguration config;
    private readonly IAccessTokenProvider authenticationService;

    private readonly Lazy<Task<GrpcChannel>> channel;

    public GrpcChannelProvider(
        IConfiguration config, IAccessTokenProvider authenticationService)
    {
        this.config = config;
        this.authenticationService = authenticationService;

        this.channel = new Lazy<Task<GrpcChannel>>(this.CreateChannel);
    }

    public Task<GrpcChannel> Channel => this.channel.Value;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.channel.IsValueCreated) this.channel.Value.Dispose();
    }

    // This is your original code
    private async Task<GrpcChannel> CreateChannel()
    {
#if DEBUG
        var baseUri = "http://localhost:8999/";
#else
var baseUri = "[mysite]";
#endif
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new GrpcWebHandler(GrpcWebMode.GrpcWeb, new HttpClientHandler()));

        var tokenResult = await this.authenticationService.RequestAccessToken();

        if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
        {
            var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.Value))
                {
                    metadata.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.Value}");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(baseUri,
                new GrpcChannelOptions
                {
                    HttpClient = httpClient,
                    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials)
                });

            var client = new GrpcServices.GrpcServicesClient(channel);
            return client;
        }
    }
}
```

This component can be registered as follows:

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IGrpcChannelProvider, GrpcChannelProvider>();
```

Or -in case caching the channel for the duration of the app domain causes security concerns- register the component as scoped:

```cs
services.AddScoped<IGrpcChannelProvider, GrpcChannelProvider>();
```

In the view, inject this `IGrpcChannelProvider` instead of the channel:

```cs
@inject IGrpcChannelProvider Provider
```

And use it as follows:

```cs
var channel = await Provider.Channel;
GetAllResponse getAllResponse =
    await channel.GetAllAsync(new Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Empty());
```

To take it one step further, you might even want to prevent doing any calls on services inside your Razor page, but instead rely on a pre-populated model:

@model AllResponseModel

```cs
@model AllResponseModel

GetAllResponse getAllResponse = Model.AllResponses;
```

Now you can inject `IGrpcChannelProvider` into the Razor `AllResponseModel` instead.

Comment: Thank you.  I have actually been working to implement the advice in the article you posted before, but these specific instructions will certainly make that task easier.